# How to convert milliseconds to Stopwatch format in Kotlin? (HH:MM:SS)

Tags: kotlin

I have time in milliseconds which i'm getting by:

```
    val past = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val future = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000L
    
    // getting duration every second. imagine working stopwatch here
    val duration = future - past
    
    // Imconvert duration to HH:MM:SS
```

. I need to convert it to stopwatch format (HH:MM:SS). I know there is a lot of options. But what is the most modern and easiest way to do it?

Comment: The "stopwatch" format you are referring to seems to be a format for a duration (some amount of elapsed time). But since you wrote "Unix time in milliseconds" to describe what you have, it seems to be a timestamp, which represents an instant in time (and by Unix I'm assuming it's encoded as the number of milliseconds since Epoch). Those 2 things are quite different, it's not about formatting but semantics. Could you please give an example of what you're looking for exactly?

Comment: @Joffrey sure, sorry. I will edit my question right now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more Kotlin-style straightforward way of doing this:

```
val durationString = duration.milliseconds.toComponents { hours, minutes, seconds, _ ->
    "%02d:%02d:%02d".format(hours, minutes, seconds)
}
```

Where the `.milliseconds` extension is from `import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.milliseconds`

Comment: It works amazing. Looks even better. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

### Be careful how you get milliseconds in the first place

First and foremost, you should not use `System.currentTimeMillis()` for elapsed time. This clock is meant for wallclock time and is subject to drifting or leap second adjustments that can mess up your measurements significantly.

A better clock to use would be `System.nanoTime()`. But in Kotlin you don't need to call it explicitly if you want to measure elapsed time. You can use nice utilities like [measureNanoTime](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.system/measure-nano-time.html), or the experimental [measureTime](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.time/measure-time.html) which directly returns a `Duration` that you can format:

```kotlin
val durationNanos = measureNanoTime {
    // run the code to measure
}

val duration = measureTime {
    // run the code to measure
}
```

### Convert milliseconds to `Duration`

If you don't want to use `measureTime` and still have just a number of milliseconds or nanoseconds, you can convert them to a `Duration` by using one of the extension properties of `Duration.Companion`:

```kotlin
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.milliseconds

val durationMillis: Long = 1000L // got from somewhere
val duration: Duration = durationMillis.milliseconds
```

However, that is quite awkward and that's the reason why those extensions were deprecated for a while. They were restored because they are nice to use with number literals, but they are not so nice with variable names. Instead, you can use `Long.toDuration()`:

```kotlin
import kotlin.time.*

val durationMillis = 1000L // got from somewhere
val duration = durationMillis.toDuration(DurationUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

### Format `Duration`

If you just want a nice visual format, note that the `kotlin.time.Duration` type is already printed nicely thanks to its nice `toString` implementation:

```kotlin
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.minutes
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.seconds
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.milliseconds

fun main() {
    val duration = 4.minutes + 67.seconds + 230.milliseconds
    println(duration) // prints 5m 7.23s
}
```

See it in the playground: https://pl.kotl.in/YUT6FZA0l

If you really want the format you're asking for, you may also use `toComponents` as @Can_of_awe mentioned:

```kotlin
// example duration, built from extensions on number literals
val duration = 4.minutes + 67.seconds + 230.milliseconds

val durationString = duration.toComponents { hours, minutes, seconds, _ ->
    "%02d:%02d:%02d".format(hours, minutes, seconds)
}
println(durationString) // prints 00:05:07
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer but i will give best solution to @Can_of_awe. Sorry :)

Comment: No need to apologize about it. I just chose to cover your wider use case with best practices instead of focusing on the exact question, but technically the other answer is to-the-point and rather correct.